# operator< for list sorting

Tags: c++

I have a simple Position struct:

```
struct Position
{
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

I also have a list of Positions:

```
std::list<Position> positons;
```

I'm trying to sort the list using list::sort() and need to define operator< for Positions objects. I tried keeping it simple creating something like:

```
bool operator<(const Position& one, const Position& two)
{
    return one.x < two.x && one.y < two.y;
}
```

But that doesn't work. How do I determine that one class/struct object as a whole is less than another? How would I do it for my Position struct?

**EDIT** When I call positions.sort(), I get a debug assertion failed which says:
Expression: invalid operator<

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? According to your function definition, one position is smaller than another if _both_ x and y are smaller. Perhaps that is not what you want. Perhaps you want: One is smaller than the other if x is smaller, or x is equal and y is smaller?

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work? Seems alright to me

Comment: _How_ doesn't it work? Are you defining your operator as a free-standing function or as a member of some class/struct?

Comment: Added more info to the edit. i get an invalid operator< assertion when calling sort().

Comment: Code aside, there is confusion of what you really want your ordering to be. Can you specify in your question, **in words (not code)** what you want the sort order to be? "Given two `Position` objects `left` and `right`, I want `left` to be considered "less" than `right` if...."

Comment: So you don't care about the ordering itself, as long as it allows you to spot duplicates?

Comment: OK, then also keep Mankarse's solution in mind. It requires C++11 support, but it is a very compact way to provide lexicographical ordering, and scales easily to higher numbers of variables to compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort by x and then by y. Also define it as free function:

```
bool function(const Position& one, const Position& two)
{
    return one.x < two.x || (one.x == two.x && one.y < two.y);
}
```

Or as `operator`:

```
bool operator<(const Position& other)const
{
    return x < other.x || (x == other.x && y < other.y);
}
```

Comment: +1 This sorts X-dominant, which the OP did not specifically ask for, but I'm not sure they know for sure what they want. In most cases, however, this is *exactly* what they want.

Comment: This is actually just what I was needed. Makes perfect sense now that I see it on paper.

Comment: @user974967 I kinda figured it would be. It almost always is when sorting (x,y) points.

Answer (score 3):

Your current definition does not establish a [strict weak order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering). Try something like:

```
bool operator<(const Position& one, const Position& two)
{
    return std::tie(one.x, one.y) < std::tie(two.x, two.y);
}
```

This uses [std::tie](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) to create two `std::tuple<int const&, int const&>` objects containing references to the `x` and `y` elements of `one` and `two`, and then compares the two tuples using [operator<](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp) (which performs a [lexicographical comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)).

`std::tie` requires C++11, but a similar result can be achieved with [boost::tuple](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html).

Answer (score 2):

You could sort your positions by distance from origin, or magnitude, like so:

```
std::vector<Position> Foo;
std::sort(Foo.begin(), Foo.end(), [](Position& a, Position& b) {return (abs(a.x) + abs(a.y)) <  (abs(b.x) + abs(b.y)); });
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to forgo the `struct` and use

```
typedef std::array< int, 2 > Position; // C++11, access pos[0] and pos[1]
```

or

```
typedef std::pair< int, int > Position; // C++03, access pos.first and pos.second
```

These classes have `operator<` (and all the other operators you might need) predefined. You can't call the coordinates `.x` and `.y`, but it's better than reinventing the wheel.

If you really want, there's also a trick to call the members of `std::array` as `x` and `y`, in a fashion:

```
enum coord_name { x, y, z };

template< typename lhs_t >
auto operator ->* ( lhs_t &&lhs, coord_name rhs )
    -> decltype( lhs[ + rhs ] )
    { return lhs[ + rhs ]; }

Position coords;
std::array< float, 3 > coords_3d_floating;

// usage:
coords->*x = 8;
coords->*y = coords_3d_floating->*z * 1.5;
```

This requires C++11.